# Make function to check login status with session in PHP

Tags: php, html

i want to make toefl test. so there will be a login button. when someone login in, then the login button will be logout button. but when i login in, the login button was not changed. please help me

function to check login status (i save this function in lib_function.php):

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php 
 function check_login(){
    $hasil = 0;

    if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    $mail = $_SESSION['email'];
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['pass'])) {
    $pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
    }

    if (!empty($mail) and !empty($pass)){
        $hasil = 1;
    }

    return $hasil;
  }
 ?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php session_start();
require_once("connection.php");
?>
<?php include("lib_function.php"); ?>

<--header-->

   <?php 
            $check = check_login();

            if ($check == 1){
              echo "<a href=\"login.php\">Login</a> <strong class=\"hover\">";
            }else{
              echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a> <strong class=\"hover\">";
            }
          ?>
```

this is my login process:

```
<?php 
session_start();

    require_once("connection.php");

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $cekuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email'");
    $jumlah = mysql_num_rows($cekuser);
    $hasil = mysql_fetch_array($cekuser);

    if($jumlah == 0) {
        echo "<script>alert('Email has registered!'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
    } else {
        if($pass > $hasil['password']) {
        echo "<script>alert('Wrong password!'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
        } else {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $hasil['email'];
        header('location:index.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: can please show the login page code

Comment: make sure you have `session_start()` on top in `lib_function.php` page before `<html>tag</html>`

Comment: @Hosseini Why?  session_start() is called at the very top of index.php and the file described as "this is my login process".

Comment: @VolkerK yes no need its includeded but its added after my comment

Answer (score 0):

You check if `$_SESSION['pass']` is set in your `check_login` function, but you never set it during the login process.

Either set `$_SESSION['pass']` or remove `and !empty($pass)` from `check_login()`.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to check if the Session is already active before starting one. You also might want to assign default values of say NULL to the $mail & $pass variables inside your check_login() function because at a point, you were checking if $mail and $pass were empty. What if they were not even set at all? In this case those variables would not have existed at all...

```
    <?php
    // FILE:: lib_function.php
     function check_login(){
         $hasil = 0;
         // GET THE $mail & $pass FROM SESSION; ASSIGNING A DEFAULT NULL
         // TO EACH OF THEM IF THEY ARE NOT YET SET...
         $mail  = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email']    : null;
         $pass  = isset($_SESSION['pass'])  ? $_SESSION['pass']     : null;

         if (!empty($mail) and !empty($pass)){
             $hasil = 1;
         }
         return $hasil;
     }



    // FILE:: index.php
    // START SESSION ONLY IF IT IS NOT ALREADY ACTIVE:
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }

    require_once("connection.php");
    include("lib_function.php");

    // HEADER HERE

    $check  = check_login();

    if ($check == 1){
        echo "<a href=\"login.php\">Login</a> <strong class=\"hover\">";
    }else{
        echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a> <strong class=\"hover\">";
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
function login($email) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
}

function is_logged() {
    return isset($_SESSION['email']);
}

function logout() {
    session_destroy();
}
```